Get last data available (currency table incomplete) - SQL / BigQuery
This is my schema:
Schema
I have a currency table and a fact table. My currency table doesn't have the rates for all days, so when this happens, I would like to get the last exchange rate available.
For example, if I don't have an exchange rate for 04/02/2024, I need to get the rate of 03/02/2024. Of course, it's important to maintain the consistency of the currencies, so I need to get the last rate available for that particular currency.
I am trying to do that in BigQuery, but so far, I not succeeded.
I need a table as shown here, repeating the last exchange rate of the currency available in the database.
This is the table I need

Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted

Why did the exchange rate for 6th became 1.11? Shouldn't it be 1.10 for 6th too?
